# Download SVG as JPEG using flask

Tags: python, flask, operating-system, jpeg, encode

I'm trying to serve HTML page with SVG attributes on it; so as soon as I click "Create" I want to be able to download that file as .jpg instead of SVG. I looked over at multiple convertors that works with the command line for instance like this.

```
os.system("rsvg-convert -h 32 save.svg > icon-32.jpg")
```

Similiary, I want to be able to click create and download the .jpg version of my file. 
I'm currently trying to do this using Flask.

```
without_filter = <svg viewBox="0 0 400 150" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background: #40484b;">
    <defs>
        <!-- if you use the same shape multiple times, you put the reference here and reference it with <use> -->
        <rect id="path-1" x="25" y="25" width="100" height="100"></rect>
        <rect id="path-3" x="150" y="25" width="100" height="100"></rect>
        <rect id="path-5" x="275" y="25" width="100" height="100"></rect>

        <!-- gradient -->
        <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="gradient">
            <stop stop-color="#FF8D77" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#FFBDB1" offset="50%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#F4E3F6" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>

        <!-- clip-path -->
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <circle cx="325" cy="75" r="50"></circle>
        </clipPath>

        <!-- filter -->
        <filter x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="glow">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15" in="SourceGraphic">
                <animate attributeName="stdDeviation" attributeType="XML"
                    begin="0s" dur="0.25s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                    values="15;20;15"/>
            </feGaussianBlur>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill-rule="evenodd">
        <use xlink:href="#path-1" filter="url(#glow)" fill="#FF8D77" fill-opacity="0.5"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#path-3" fill="url(#gradient)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#path-5" fill="#FF8D77" clip-path="url(#clip)"></use>
    </g>
</svg>
```

So I'm trying to download the (html) as .jpeg as soon as the user clicks "create"
Here's my view function.

```
@app.route('/filters/<filename>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def AddFiltersTag(filename):
    form = AddFilterTags(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        html = re.sub(r'(.*?<defs>)(.*)', r'\g<1>' + add_filter_tag + add_filter + end_tag + '\g<2>', without_filter)
        save_html = open('save.svg','wb')
        save_html.write(html)
        os.system("rsvg-convert -h 32 save.svg > icon-32.jpg")
        return download_html
```

So that function AddFilterTag gets trigged when a user clicks "Submit" at my form. but in that case I want to download, the above code simply saves the file as .svg and converts it later on using os.system, But I want to actually download the .jpg version directly. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have not tried this myself since I don't use flask, but there are python bindings for the rsvg library that you might want to use instead. That way, you can maybe pass the contents from 'html' directly rather than writing them out to an svg file to be used as a parameter in an 'rsvg-convert' command.

Answer (score 0):

After saving the file and converting it into an image.

You can directly return the file from the directory, which will give a download popup to the user.

```
...
os.system("rsvg-convert -h 32 save.svg > icon-32.jpg")
return send_from_directory("/path/to/saved/image", "icon-32.jpg")
```

Be sure to import the method as follows:

```
from flask import send_from_directory
```

If you're using this in production, make sure nginx or an actual web server is sending the file. You can read more at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.send_from_directory

Comment: Hey, when I click create button it throws me 404 NOT found.

Comment: that's my code.save_html = open('static/save.svg','wb')
        save_html.write(html)
        transfer_file_name = 'icon-32.jpg'
        os.system("rsvg-convert -h "+height+""+filename+" > "+transfer_file_name)
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, "icon-32.jpg")